# PrimeFaces CommandButton does not invoke managed bean method at first click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with the **first** ajax requests sending by the PrimeFaces components. It occured in many cases, so I tried to make a very small example. My xhtml file is the following:

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Remote Command Tutorial</title>
</h:head>
<h:body id="body">
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />

    <h:form id="form">
        <h:inputText  converter="javax.faces.Integer" id="input" value="#{remoteCommandBean.value}"></h:inputText>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function increment() {
                var value = parseInt($("#form\\:input").val())+1 ;

                $("#form\\:input").val(value) ;
            }
        </script>

        <h:commandButton type="submit"  onclick="increment()" update="input">
            <f:ajax></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>

<p:commandButton type="submit"  onclick="increment()" update="input"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the managed bean:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RemoteCommandBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int value = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So, the small application contains an input field which is bounded to a managed bean property, and there are two command buttons: first is a standard JSF button, and the second is a PrimeFaces command button. Both of them invoke a javascript method, which increments the number in the input field, and (hopefully) an ajax request is sent in order to refresh the bean property, then the response refresh the field again, with the same number. My problem is that **when I push the PrimeFaces button first, it does not refresh the number correctly, actually its value remains the initial 0.** After second click, everything works fine, and this problem does not occure with the standard button. I've checked (in Chrome) the difference between the first and the following requests, and I've found the following:

First request:

```
form:input:1
form_SUBMIT:1
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:form:j_idt9
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
javax.faces.partial.render:form:input
form:j_idt9:form:j_idt9
```

Second:

```
form:input:1
form_SUBMIT:1
javax.faces.ViewState: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
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:form:j_idt9
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
javax.faces.partial.render:form:input
form:j_idt9:form:j_idt9
```

We use Glassfish 3.1.2, PrimeFaces 3.2, and Apache-MyFaces 2.0.2.

Could anyone help me?

smoketriad

Comment: 1st submit doesn't have the viewstate which explains the whole problem. But I can't explain why the viewstate isn't there. Normally, in JSF 2.0/2.1, the viewstate will be missing when the one of the parent components of the `<h:form>` has been re-rendered by *another form* by ajax beforehand. But this doesn't seem to be the case in your SSCCE. Or did you oversimplify the code without actually testing the code shown so far?

Comment: I tested this code. (Can this phenomena be caused by a wrong configuration? Because the example is very simple, I think maybe my Eclipse project configuration has some problems..)

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact the input text is not a primefaces input text. there's a rendering order between JSF and Primefaces. could also be you need to update the form not the input from the command button.